# What is the best way to process more than 7 MB JSON file in Node

Tags: node.js, json

I have a large file of JSON (over 7 MB) and I want to iterate it to find my match data.

Is it a good a way to read the entire file in memory and keep it for next call or there are other ways which have better performance and a few memory using?

Comment: Why not store contents of that json file in a database? Databases are really good at processing queries.

Answer (score 1):

Data stored in the JSON format is meant to be read in all at once.  That's how the format works.  It's not a format that you would generally incrementally search without first reading all the data in.  While there are some modules that support streaming it in and somewhat examining it incrementally, that is not what the format was intended for, nor what it is best suited for.

So, you really have several questions to ask yourself:

1. Can you read the whole block of data into memory at once and parse it into Javascript?
2. Is the amount of memory it takes to do that OK in your environment?
3. Is the time to do that OK for your application?
4. Can you cache it in memory for awhile so you can more efficiently access it the next time you need something from it?
5. Or, should this data really be in a database that supports efficient searches and efficient modifications with far lower memory usage and much better performance?

If you're OK with the first four questions, then just read it in, parse it and keep the resulting Javascript object in memory.  If you're not OK with any of the first four questions, then you probably should put the data into a format that can more efficiently be queried without loading it all into memory (e.g. a simple database).